# Angular material prebuilt css overriding custom theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, themes

I have created a custom angular material theme and imported it into angular.json.
The theme only works if I remove the prebuilt theme css import from styles.css, however then all my `mat-select` components open at the bottom of the page. (importing the prebuilt css fixes that problem)

Theme import in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "src/bookstore-theme.scss",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
```

bookstore-theme.scss:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
$bookstore-theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette, 400);
$bookstore-theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$purple-palette, A200, A100, A400);
$bookstore-theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$bookstore-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $bookstore-theme-primary,
    accent: $bookstore-theme-accent,
    warn: $bookstore-theme-warn,
  )
));

@include mat.core-theme($bookstore-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($bookstore-theme);
```

Import in styles.css: `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Comment: remove the `@import` in your styles.css, this import is overriding your theme. a [stackblitz with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9415a3?file=src%2Ftheme.scss)

Comment: removing the `@import` from styles.css applies my theme correctly, however it causes issues with the `<mat-select>` element. Without the imported css, the select field opens at the bottom of my page, which doesn't happen with the prebuilt css imported.

Comment: Putting my theme at the bottom fixed it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As Eliseo pointed out, putting the `styles.css` above the custom theme file fixed the issue.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css",
  "src/bookstore-theme.scss"
],
```

Comment: **NOT** is the correct answer: the problem is that you forgot add: `@include mat.core();` just before the line: `@use '@angular/material' as mat;` I know that I wrote the comment but I feel that was erroneous. I update the stackblitz also

Comment: The custom theme actually works without the line you mentioned.

Comment: I want to say that if you include the line, you needn't add the `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"` (see the stackblitz)